# include additional stylesheet in header.php for specific page

Tags: php, html, css, php-include

I have a very basic php template configured for the pages in my website, in which each `index.php` includes a `header.php`, `footer.php`, etc. I have a specific instance in which I'd like to include an additional set of styles for one section of the site only, and I'm wondering how I might "inject" an additional stylesheet into the `header.php` for this specific case? Thus, I'd rather that the rest of the pages in the site not load this CSS since it really only applies to this one section. I'd prefer to keep things clean, if possible, and not include the CSS inline.

I'm wondering if perhaps I could use `isset` or something along those lines in the `header.php` by which I could include an additional stylesheet in the cases for which it's needed, defined by a variable in the appropriate `index.php`?

Thanks for any assistance here.

*UPDATE* for any future visitors seeking an answer to this question, I used the following in my `header.php` which worked well:

```
<?php
    if (isset($section_specific_styles))
    {
        echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"main/css/{$section_specific_styles}.css\">";
    }
?>
```

I then set the variable `$section_specific_styles` for those pages that require additional styles.

Comment: a simple conditional statement surely isn't that hard to figure out. We have no idea how your routing or page controllers work to give you specifics

Comment: you'd need to check if the current page equals something, then `{ do something }`

Comment: @charlietfl-- a simple suggestion to look into conditional statements would have sufficed, thank you.

Comment: @nickpish after 4 years knowing how and what to ask on S.O would be nice

Comment: @Dagon-- not here to engage in nonsense; I asked a specific question. Contribute productively or don't contribute at all.

Comment: you say it's "specific" the close voters say the complete opposite

Comment: again, thanks for the productive feedback; this sort of "moderation" is the complete opposite of helpful. clearly there were attempts to answer the question before it was shut down. why not actually attempt to be helpful rather than condescending?

Answer (score 2):

One way that you could do this is by looking at the URI and putting in the appropriate CSS file based on checking for the existence of a string.

```
 <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"gallery")>-1) { ?>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/gallery.css" />
 <?php } ?>
```

or if you are using query parameters to determine what page you are on you would do something like this in the header.php file:

```
 <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],"gallery")>-1) { ?>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/gallery.css" />
 <?php } ?>
```

This would be somewhat safe to put in the header.php file for every page since it would only include the stylesheet when on a URI that had "gallery" within it, but this isn't the best method to do this as it requires you to keep track of pages and sections in code. But still, if you had to do it this way this would be one way to make that work.

Comment: someone is confusing php with js

Comment: thanks for the catch, I've been in JS all day that it seeped into my PHP

Answer (score 2):

You could do a test for the page url and add your css only if the condition is true. In the code below, I am checking the url of the page and saving it to the `$page` variable. Then I check to see if the needle(something) can be found in `haystack($page)`, and if so make our css available.

```
<?php 
  $page = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $css ='<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">';
  if (false !== strpos($page,'something')) { //test for some string
    echo $css;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.

Comment: @peterh Thought I had, but happy to add more info. I just edited my answer to give some more explanation. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Not I did it, but his reason was probably similar as my comment. If you fix your answer, I will compensate it with an up.

Comment: Exactly. :-) The reason behind that, that this site is theoretically not a help site, but it is also for the googlers of the future. This is why a code snippet is not enough.

Comment: @bklynM--thanks for the response; that's an interesting approach.